# Jboss idea unable to ping server at localhost:8080

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

Пытаюсь запустить сервер приложения runawfe(есть на гитхабе), собрал в мавене, теперь пытаюсь запустить на сервере jboss, появляется такая ошибка Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:8080.
Вот весь лог ошибки, да, часть ошибки написана иероглифами, может ответ кроется там:
C:\Users\Александр\IdeaProjects\runawfe-serv\wildfly\bin\standalone.bat
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath101180561 com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 53448 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
Detected server admin port: 9990
Detected server http port: 8080
"findstr" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
[2018-08-16 06:28:58,075] Artifact runawfe-serv:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Disconnected from server

Для запуска jboss требует наличие артефакта, указал файл который генерируется в процессе сборки программы - runawfe.ear - не знаю правильно это или нет.
Находил советы по добавлению имени компьютера в файл hosts - не помогло.
Пробовал разные sdk(7,8,10) - не помогло.
Пробовал разные версии jboss...
Менял порты, проверял что именно этот порт не занят.
Подозреваю что проблема простая, но я новичок в разработке и не знаю как решить, весь интернет перерыл уже.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно было всего то скопировать файл findstr из windows/system32 в bin сервера и на всякий случай скопировал его в бин всех сдк, кто бы мог подумать.